# Radio button change image when checked

Tags: javascript, html, css

What I've wanted to happen that there are only images to be displayed and these images are **RADIO BUTTONS** , everytime I select or do checked I want to change the image of it.

something like this:
[image: Buttons DIsplayed]

Here's my code so far.

```css
.button input[type="radio"] {
    display: none;
}

.button input[type=radio]:checked + label>img {
   background:url("https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/small-n-flat/24/678134-sign-check-128.png") no-repeat;
}

.button input[type=radio]:hover + label>img {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
        -ms-transform: scale(1.3);
        transform: scale(1.3);
}
```

```html
<div class="button">
<input type="radio" id="but1" name="sel_button"   />  
<label for="close"> <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-close-circled-128.png" alt="close_icon"/> </label> 

<input type="radio" id="but2" name="sel_button"   />  
<label for="bulb"> <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/117/117944.png" alt="bulb_icon"/> </label> 

</div>
```

They can't seem to be clickable and my hover isn't working.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: your input type radio has display none so you cant hover on it

Comment: and also you are giving the image a background its not shown because image will overlay it

Comment: @Araz about the image, I've prepared the images to have a low capacity. Will this still works?

Comment: @hungerstar I see, i wanted to look like this so i hide it http://codepen.io/DavidBradbury/pen/HuCqx

Comment: @Bonnet_Stelle I take it back. It will work when using `display: none;` if the value of the `id` of the `input` and the `for` attribute of the `label` have the same value. Yours do not match. i.e. it should be `id="but1"` and `for="but1"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using value inside 'for' attribute correctly. It should be the id of the element it is referring

```css
.button input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

.button input[type=radio]:checked + label > img {
  background: url("https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/small-n-flat/24/678134-sign-check-128.png") no-repeat;
}

.button input[type=radio]:hover + label  >img {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.3);
  transform: scale(1.3);
}
```

```html
<div class="button">

  <input type="radio" id="but1" name="sel_button">
  <label for="but1">
    <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-close-circled-128.png" alt="close_icon"/>
  </label>

  <input type="radio" id="but2" name="sel_button">
  <label for="but2">
    <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/117/117944.png" alt="bulb_icon"/>
  </label>

</div>
```